# Is there an another way to get date instead of getting it from user's device

Tags: javascript, date

I want to make an application that will only open at a specific date. I use `new date()` to do that, but `new date()` get time from the user's device and the the user can open it by changing the time on its own device.

Example:

```
  let setdate = new Date('2021-12-10')
   let currentdate = new Date()
   console.log(setdate)
   if(setdate.getDate() == currentdate.getDate()){
    document.getElementById("result").style.display = 'revert'
   }
```

```
<div id=result style="display:none">Open now!!!</div>
```

If I don't do anything with the time of my device, it won't do anything. But if I change the date on my device to the specific date, then the area could open.

Could anyone suggests me a better way that could prevent this situation or is there an another way to get date instead of getting it from user's device

Thanks for any responds!!!

Comment: 1. let backend exposed its time. 2. 12/9 should be caused by time zone, it should be utc time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call API, and let your frontend behaves according to its response
`https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone` has good API for that.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<h2>Loading ...</h2>'

fetch("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London")
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => {
    let now = new Date(data.datetime);
    myLogicPerDate(now);
   
  })
  
  
  
function myLogicPerDate(date) {

    if (date.getMinutes() % 2 ) {
       document.body.innerHTML = "You cannot see anything because it's EVEN minute"
    } else {
       document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Welcome page</h1>You are allowed to see anything because it's ODD minute"
    
    }

}
```

> **DISCLAIMER** Relying on free API is not a reliable way. So either you pay to have highest SLA from your vendor, or implement your own API & maintain its reliability.